# Refresh or manual URL typing in SSR React App changes a className

Tags: reactjs, sass, react-router, server-side-rendering

The App was initially made with CRA and converted into SSR. The app works fine but the problem arises only when I refresh the app or manually type in the URL to a certain page. The middle div's classname is then overridden to the classname of the middle div of the base route.

It changes for example from this:

```
<div id="root">
   <div class="header">..</div>
   <div class="newlist">..</div>
   <div class="footer">..</div>   
</div>
```

to this:

```
<div id="root">
   <div class="header">..</div>
   <div class="main-flex-container">..</div>
   <div class="footer">..</div>   
</div>
```

For extra information here is my src/index.js:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import configureStore, { history } from './redux/store/index';
import AppRouter from './routers/AppRouter';
import './styles/styles.scss';

const store = configureStore();

require('dotenv').config();

const isServer = typeof window !== 'undefined';

if (isServer) {
  ReactDOM.hydrate(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <AppRouter />
      </BrowserRouter>
    </Provider>,
    document.getElementById('root'),
  );
}
```

and here is my server.js:

```
import express from 'express';
import fs from 'fs';
import path from 'path';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOMServer from 'react-dom/server';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import configureStore from '../src/redux/store/index';
import AppRouter from '../src/routers/AppRouter';
import { StaticRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const app = express();
const store = configureStore();

app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build')));

app.use('/*', (req, res, next) => {
  fs.readFile(path.resolve('./build/index.html'), 'utf-8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      return res.send(500).send('Error happened!');
    }
    return res.send(
      data.replace(
        '<div id="root"></div>',
        `<div id="root">${ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
          <Provider store={store}>
            <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={{}}>
              <AppRouter />
            </StaticRouter>
          </Provider>,
        )}</div>`,
      ),
    );
  });
});

app.listen(3000, () => {
  console.log('Listening...');
});
```

In case this isn't enough information, here is the [link](https://github.com/DzhideX/colabico-clone/tree/master/frontend) to the project on GitHub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the crux of your problem here seems to be that when rendered on the server, the router isn't rendering the correct component based on the url as we would expect.

What is happening is not that the class name is changed, instead we are actually always rendering the root page and then react replaces the content with the "new task" page on the client before you get a chance to have a look at it in the inspector.

Summary: When using `app.use` with a path in express, we are mounting an express middleware at the specified path, and express removes the "mount point" from the `req.url` provided to the middleware. Among other solutions, we can use `req.originalUrl` to get the actual url. `req.originalUrl` is a property provided by express that gives the url as it was before any middleware changed it.

---

Let's investigate!

If we extract the code that renders your app to a separate variable and log that, we will see that the logged HTML string is the page with the "New List" button on it.

```js
const renderedApp = ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <StaticRouter location={req.url} context={{}}>
      <AppRouter />
    </StaticRouter>
  </Provider>,
);
console.log('Rendered app', renderedApp);
return res.send(
  data.replace(
    '<div id="root"></div>',
    `<div id="root">${renderedApp}</div>`,
  ),
);
```

Visiting `localhost:3000/l/new` and looking in the log:

```
Rendered app <div class="header"><a class="header__button" id="header__colabico" href="/">COLABI.CO</a><div class="header__right"><button class="header__button" id="header__tweet">TWEET</button><button class="header__button" id="header__logout">LOGOUT</button></div></div><div class="main-flex-container"><a class="home__button" href="/l/new"> <!-- -->NEW LIST<!-- --> </a><p class="home__infotext"> <!-- -->Start by pressing that big button up there!<!-- --> </p></div><div class="footer"><div class="footer__left"><a class="footer__button" href="/privacy">PRIVACY</a><a class="footer__button" href="/terms">TERMS</a></div><p class="footer__colabico"> © colabi.co</p></div>
```

This looks very much like the root page instead of the new list page.

Aside: Putting the rendering on a separate line instead of inline in the template string also helps with syntax highlighting, as a nice bonus.

Aside 2: By adding this logging you'll also see that your code is not run when hitting the root url. The reason for this is probably because of the static middleware at the start, which will match on the `index.html` page in your build folder.

Now that we are fairly certain what the problem is, let's try to see why it might be.

The `StaticRouter` accepts the location as a prop, and we are passing in `req.url` for that. Let's verify that this is what we think it is.

```js
console.log('URL:', req.url);
```

When visiting `localhost:3000/l/new`, this is logged:

```
URL: /
```

That is certainly not what we expected!

I went to look up the documentation for `req.url` to see what the problem might be, and found this method:

[`req.originalUrl`](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.originalUrl)

I couldn't see the documentation for `req.url`, but there's a helpful box here explaining why that is (`req.url` comes from Node's http module).

Logging `req.originalUrl` too just to see what that is for us, and sure enough:

```
original URL: /l/new
URL: /
```

`req.originalUrl` has what we need!

At this point I searched around for references to explain why `req.url` might be `/` in our case, and it turns out it's because of this:

When we are using `app.use`, we are mounting an express middleware at the specified path, rather than setting up a route handler (that would be `app.get` or similar), and middlewares remove the path they are mounted at from their own url, because they consider that their `root`. When we specify the middleware to be mounted at `/*`, the wildcard matches all routes and the whole url is removed.

In other words, we can fix this in a few different ways:

1. Keep it as it is, but use `req.originalUrl` instead
2. Remove the path from `app.use` (`app.use((req, res, next) => {/* your code */})`)
3. Change from `app.use` to `app.get`

Hope that helps!

Comment: Really nice answer Kim! Glad you were able to dig deeper into this. I need to work more on my SSR knowledge myself lol

Comment: yoo it's working totally fine but, somewhere missing  css ( http://localhost:8000/static/css/main.8c8b27cf.chunk.css )